# JQuery element creation

Tags: jquery

Typically I create elements using $("", {}) but I'm running into an issue with certain DOM properties. Any of the properties with camel case, like innerHTML, are set to lower case and then jquery give the elements a custom property. How do I prevent this?

```
$("p", { "innerHTML" : "<a>text</a>"})
```

I expect: `<p><a>text</a></p>`
Instead I get `<p innerhtml="<p><a>text</a></p>">`

This is true for any property using camel case.

Comment: Use `html`, not `innerHTML`, and `'p'` is a selector. To create an element use `'<p />'`. See the docs: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements

Comment: Rory is right, just like html()

Comment: I've posted a solution to your problem below. If you post the additional camel case properties that you're having a problem with, I can edit those into the example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery `.html()` as the object attribute that you pass in, not the native DOM `innerHTML`:

```js
$("<p />", { "html" : "<a>text</a>"}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Is there a list of  these changes or a rule to thumb I can follow?

Comment: The "list" is to use the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com) and find the attribute / property that you're seeking.

Comment: @UselessIntern As a general rule of thumb, I'd say to look and see if jQuery has a respective method for the property you want to set (i.e. `.html()` for `innerHTML`). However, if not as in the case of `src` for images, you nest the properties in a `.attr()` object in the definition. Consider the following example: `$('<img />', { attr: { src: "some-link.jpg" }});`

Comment: Ah I see, I thought it was a nice one-to-one mapping. Thanks for the tips.